# How to differentiate 'k' copies of an input Tensor [Swift for TensorFlow]

Tags: swift, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

## Task

I am attempting to implement the [Gated-GAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02296.pdf) architecture using Swift for TensorFlow. In the generator of the Gated-GAN, there are `k` convolutional blocks (the "Gated-Transformer"), each of which take in a copy of the encoded image. The output of this layer is a single, weighted sum of the outputs of each convolutional block.

In the future, I would like to be able to increase `k` after a model has already been trained (and, say, fine-tune the `k+1`th transformer). As such, I don't want to hard-code `k` into the architecture.

[Gated-Transformer diagram (I don't have enough reputation to post the picture directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDxxq.png)

## Minimal Working Example

It would be very convenient to write something like this:

```swift
struct GatedTransformer: Layer {

    // Normally the blocks in the transformer are residual blocks, but
    // for simplicity I'll just use Conv2D here.
    var convBlocks: [Conv2D<Float>]

    /// Custom differentiable input (needed since the layer has two inputs).
    struct GatedTransformerInput: Differentiable {
        var image: Tensor<Float>  // shape=[batch_size, height, width, channel]
        var classDistributions: Tensor<Float>  // shape=[class_count]

        @differentiable
        public init(image: Tensor<Float>, classDistributions: Tensor<Float>) {
            self.image = image
            self.classDistributions = classDistributions
        }
    }

    public init(_ classCount: Int) {
        precondition(classCount > 0)

        // Some example parameters for Conv2D.
        convBlocks = [Conv2D](repeating: Conv2D(filterShape: (3, 3, 128, 128), strides: (1, 1)), count: classCount)
    }

    var classCount: Int { get { return convBlocks.count } }

    @differentiable
    func callAsFunction(_ input: GatedTransformerInput) -> Tensor<Float> {
        precondition(input.classDistributions.shape.dimensions.last! == self.classCount)

        // <problematic_code id=0>
        var imageArray: [Tensor<Float>] = [Tensor<Float>](repeating: input.image, count: self.classCount)
        for i in 0..<self.classCount {
            imageArray[i] = convBlocks[i](input.image).expandingShape(at: 1)
        }
        let result: Tensor<Float> = Tensor<Float>(concatenating: imageArray, alongAxis: 1)
        // </problematic_code>

        // Concatenate Tensors, multiply by class distributions, then sum along 'class' axis.
        let highRankFactors: Tensor<Float> = input.classDistributions.expandingShape(at: [2, 3, 4])
        let broadcastedFactors: Tensor<Float> = highRankFactors.broadcasted(to: result.shape)
        return (broadcastedFactors * result).sum(squeezingAxes: 1)
    }
}
```

However, this fails with the compiler error:

```
cannot differentiate through a non-differentiable result; do you want to use 'withoutDerivative(at:)'?
    var imageArray: [Tensor<Float>] = [Tensor<Float>](repeating: input.image, count: self.classCount)
                                                                                     ^
```

## Alternate Approaches

#### Build a concatenated Tensor as we go along.

This approach fails because the re-assignment to `result` is not differentiable. A similar approach could be to use the Tensor `+=` operator, although this does not compile either (`Tensor.+=` is not implemented as a `@differentiable` function, according to the [official API](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/api_docs/Structs/Tensor#+=_:_:)).

```swift
// <problematic_code id=1>
var result: Tensor<Float> = convBlocks[0](input.image).expandingShape(at: 1)
for i in 0..<self.classCount {
    let nextResult: Tensor<Float> = convBlocks[i](input.image).expandingShape(at: 1)
    result = result.concatenated(with: nextResult, alongAxis: 1)
}
// </problematic_code>
```

#### Append to a new Array.

This fails because `Array.append` is not differentiable.

```swift
// <problematic_code id=2>
var imageArray: [Tensor<Float>] = []
for i in 0..<self.classCount {
    imageArray.append(convBlocks[i](input.image).expandingShape(at: 1))
}
let result: Tensor<Float> = Tensor<Float>(concatenating: imageArray, alongAxis: 1)
// </problematic_code>
```

#### Make `GatedTransformerInput` a differentiable type.

I'm assuming there is a way to get this to work. However, this would involve conforming `GatedTransformerInput` to `VectorProtocol`, which feels like more work than necessary.

#### Define custom derivative for `callAsFunction(...)`.

This could be another possible approach. However, to compute the derivative, I need to the intermediate array of `Tensor`s. These values are not visible to an outside function, which can only see the input and output of `callAsFunction(...)`

## Summarized Question

Is there a way to leverage Swift's already existing `Differentiable` types to implement the Gated-Transformer for an arbitrary (and possibly variable) `k`?

If not, how should I design a new `Differentiable` type that would allow me to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Your minimal working example is very close to doing what you want, and you can fix it with a small adjustment.

The compiler error

```
cannot differentiate through a non-differentiable result; do you want to use 'withoutDerivative(at:)'?
    var imageArray: [Tensor<Float>] = [Tensor<Float>](repeating: input.image, count: self.classCount)
                                                                                     ^
```

is happening because the compiler is trying to determine how this use of `self.classCount` contributes to the gradient. It fails while trying to do this because `self.classCount` is not differentiable (because it's a non-differentiable integer type).

In this case, you don't actually want uses of `self.classCount` to contribute to the gradient, so you can make the compiler happy by writing `withoutDerivative(at: self).classCount`. This tells the compiler to ignore how that particular use of `self` contributes to the gradient, even though the compiler is differentiating with respect to `self`.

## Alternate Approaches

Some of your alternate approaches can also work.

### Concatenated tensor

Use `withoutDerivative(at: self).classCount` in the for loop bound.

Note 1: The compiler diagnostic for this one could be improved. It's very unclear.

Note 2: I'm not sure why `withoutDerivative(at: self).classCount` isn't necessary in the for loop bound in the  first example.

### Using Tensor +=

Tensor += not differentiable because Swift AD currently (as of 2019-11-05) doesn't support differentiating mutating functions like +=. However, you should be able to differentiate functions that use `result = result + foo` instead of `result += foo`.

### Custom derivative of `callAsFunction(_:)`

When you define custom derivatives, you specify "VJP" functions that return the original result and a "pullback" closure that calculates the derivative. The "pullback" closure can capture intermediate values from the original result calculation. e.g.

```
func vjpCallAsFunction(_ input: GatedTransformerInput) -> (Tensor<Float>, ...) {
  ...
  var imageArray = ...
  ...

  func pullback(...) -> ... {
    ...
    <use imageArray>
    ...
  }

  return (result, pullback)
}
```

Of course, this causes unfortunate code duplication between `callAsFunction` and its VJP. So it's best to use automatically-calculated derivatives when that is possible.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the extremely detailed response!

I attempted to train with the first suggested solution, and it gets me past compiler errors. Unfortunately, I'm now running into the runtime error: `Precondition failed: cannot move Array.DifferentiableView with count 2 along direction with different count 0: file /swift-base/swift/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift, line 1952`

Here is the [code snippet](https://pastiebin.com/5dc365a7230b9).

I'll attempt one of the other solutions in the meantime (the `result = result + foo` solution)

Comment: It also seems like the `result = result + convBlocks[i](input.image)` solution doesn't compile, which is definitely surprising. Perhaps they'll be adding support for this when they support `Tensor.+=`. I'll cut them some slack since this project is still in beta!

Comment: More bad news; looks like the concatenation approach ends with the same runtime error as above (`Precondition failed: cannot move Array.DifferentiableView with count 2 along direction with different count 0: file /swift-base/swift/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift, line 1952`). I found a [PR from August](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/26771/files) that seems related. Perhaps I'll message the author or file a new bug report.

Comment: The precondition failure message makes me think that autodiff is producing a gradient with an empty array. Then your update step fails because you can't use an empty array to update the model that has a non-empty array.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in autodiff, possibly https://bugs.swift.org/browse/TF-933. I know that we're working on that bug right now, so it'll be interesting to see if the problem is fixed after that bug is fixed.

A bug report with full code would be really useful, in case it's actually a different bug!